# Link separates from image its attached to [middleman] css html

Tags: css, html, sass, middleman

So I have an about icon, that has a link attached to it.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("infobutton_circle_blue.png") ,"http://redbullrecords.com/artist/awolnation/", :id => "about" %>
```

this will produce this:

```
<a id="about" href="http://redbullrecords.com/artist/awolnation/" style="
    height: 40px;
"><img src="/images/infobutton_circle_blue.png"></a>
```

Before I add any styles, ... the image links so problem.

But as soon as I add a few position / sizing styles

```
        #about 
          img
            float: right
            width: 50px
            padding-right: 45px

            +rhythm(-2.0 , 0, 0, 0)
```

then the image no longer links, .. inspector says the link is on the other side of the page with a 0px x 0px size.. very strange

if anyone has ever encountered this, would love to hear how you fixed it, and what the hell im doing wrong

I tried to just target the image id without the img, .. but it didnt budge.. so thats why im using `#about img`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the space where I wanted the icon to be would technically be on top of another element, .. So I changed the styles to absolute positioning and everything worked fine, .. still very strange

```
#about 
  img
    position: absolute
    width: 50px
    padding-right: 45px
    margin-left: 70%

    +rhythm(-2.0 , 0, 0, 0)
```